# Polymer app firebase hosting deploy does not work

Tags: firebase, polymer

I have created a Polymer app using the starter kit from the yeoman generator as a starting point. The app works fine locally. After doing a full build, I did a firebase init, and a firebase deploy. I get no errors, however, when I launch the app URL, I get what looks like vulcanized JavaScript displayed in chrome.

I am not sure what is wrong. No errors reported.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Peter. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem. After running vulcanize the page would only show JavaScript instead of the actual page content. Started like:

`'),t=""+t+"";try{this.Ea.eb.open(),this.Ea.eb.write(t),this.Ea.eb.close()}catch(o){Cb("frame writing exception")...`

There was also a syntax error in the index.bundle.js, which might have caused the problem.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL -> index.build.js:13 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I couldn't get the project to run in vulcanized state afterwards. Solved the problem by creating a new poylmer starter kit project. Worked like a charm after I copied my files into the fresh directory. Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from Firebase library when you "vulcanize" your elements.

You have to exclude it from your vulcanize task (in gulpfile.js)